# How can I apply a border only inside a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I am trying to figure out how to add a border only inside the table. When I do:

```
table {
    border: 0;
}
table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The border is around the whole table and also between table cells. I want to have a border only inside the table around table cells (without an outer border around the table).

Here is the markup I'm using for tables (even though I think that is not important):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell (1,1)</td>
        <td>Cell (1,2)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell (2,1)</td>
        <td>Cell (2,2)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell (3,1)</td>
        <td>Cell (3,2)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here are some basic styles I apply to most of my tables:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: I see only borders only around the cells. Since each of the cells have a border, it appears that the table has a border. Perhaps I don't get the question?

Comment: Also called **internal borders**.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

If you are doing what I believe you are trying to do, you'll need something a little more like this:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:first-child th {
  border-top: 0;
}
table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
table tr td:first-child,
table tr th:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
table tr td:last-child,
table tr th:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/8M2wp)

The problem is that you are setting a 'full border' around all the cells, which make it appear as if you have a border around the entire table.

EDIT: A little more info on those pseudo-classes can be found on [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html), and, as to be expected, you are pretty much S.O.L. in terms of IE support.

Comment: With simple tables like this, there's a much shorter solution which avoid using pseudo-classes by using the next sibling combinator. See my answer.

Comment: @theIV, with this being answered 5+ years ago, is there any 'new'/'more efficient' way that this?

Comment: Doesn't work if you ever use rowspan on the first column in a table.

Answer (score 215):

this works for me:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-style: hidden;
}

table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[view example ...](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7Z25/show/)

tested in FF 3.6 and Chromium 5.0, IE lacks support; from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution):

> Borders with the 'border-style' of 'hidden' take precedence over all other conflicting borders. Any border with this value suppresses all borders at this location.

Comment: As long as you don't need a table border, this is definitely the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 47):

Example of a very **simple** way for you to achieve the desired effect:

```
<table border="1" frame="void" rules="all">
    <tr>
        <td>1111</td>
        <td>2222</td>
        <td>3333</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4444</td>
        <td>5555</td>
        <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: **"MAGIC" EXPLAINED:** `frame` and `rules` are **OLD (not HTML5)** `table` attributes (you should use CSS instead). `frame` says which parts of **outside** table borders should be visible - `void` means hide all outside borders... `rules` says which parts of **inside** table borders should be visible - `all` means all of them... obviously... Please don't use this, unless you are HTML3 fanatic ... :)

Comment: Adding something like border: 1px solid black will make sure the outer bound of the table gets a border.

Comment: Worked like a charm in 2020 to quickly add some readability to a ridiculously spaced table in a website I was reading. Actually, just this was enough for the internal borders: rules="all"

Comment: I used this for an E-mail body and worked like charm (2023) since CSS rules sometimes can be tricky in an E-mail body.

Answer (score 14):

For ordinary table markup, here's a short solution that works on all devices/browsers on BrowserStack, except IE 7 and below:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }

td + td,
th + th { border-left: 1px solid; }
tr + tr { border-top: 1px solid; }
```

For IE 7 support, add this:

```
tr + tr > td,
tr + tr > th { border-top: 1px solid; }
```

A test case can be seen here: http://codepen.io/dalgard/pen/wmcdE

Comment: Great - as this also allows one to set a different border to the table, rater than just not displaying it.

Comment: This is really very clever, and so short as well. I like this a lot.

Answer (score 11):

Due to mantain compatibility with ie7, ie8 I suggest using first-child and not last-child to doing this:

```
table tr td{border-top:1px solid #ffffff;border-left:1px solid #ffffff;}

table tr td:first-child{border-left:0;}

table tr:first-child td{border-top:0;}
```

You can learn about CSS 2.1 Pseudo-classes at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx

Comment: This is a great solution. But be careful, if you have another table in one of your table cells and want to see the inner borders you need another set of CSS lines for your "inner" table

Answer (score 4):

this should work:

```
table {
 border:0;
}

table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

---

edit:

i just tried it, no table border. but if i set a table border it is eliminated by the border-collapse.

this is the testfile:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


table {
    border: 0;
}
table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell (1,1)</td>
        <td>Cell (1,2)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell (2,1)</td>
        <td>Cell (2,2)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell (3,1)</td>
        <td>Cell (3,2)</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No that doesn't worked I've tried that. I will edit my first post.

Answer (score 3):

that will do it all without css
`<TABLE BORDER=1 RULES=ALL FRAME=VOID>`

code from: [HTML CODE TUTORIAL](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_179.html)

Answer (score 2):

Works for any combination of tbody/thead/tfoot and td/th

```css
table.inner-border {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

table.inner-border > thead > tr > th,
table.inner-border > thead > tr > td,
table.inner-border > tbody > tr > th,
table.inner-border > tbody > tr > td,
table.inner-border > tfoot > tr > th,
table.inner-border > tfoot > tr > td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

table.inner-border > thead > tr > :last-child,
table.inner-border > tbody > tr > :last-child,
table.inner-border > tfoot > tr > :last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}

table.inner-border > :last-child > tr:last-child > td,
table.inner-border > :last-child > tr:last-child > th {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="inner-border">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>head1,1</th>
        <td>head1,2</td>
        <td>head1,3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>head2,1</td>
        <td>head2,2</td>
        <th>head2,3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>1,1</td>
        <th>1,2</th>
        <td>1,3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2,1</td>
        <td>2,2</td>
        <td>2,3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3,1</td>
        <td>3,2</td>
        <td>3,3</td>
    </tr>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>foot1,1</th>
        <td>foot1,2</td>
        <td>foot1,3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>foot2,1</td>
        <th>foot2,2</th>
        <th>foot2,3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the border to each cell with this:

```
table > tbody > tr > td { border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); }
```

Remove the top border from all the cells in the first row:

```
table > tbody > tr:first-child > td { border-top: 0; }
```

Remove the left border from the cells in the first column:

```
table > tbody > tr > td:first-child { border-left: 0; }
```

Remove the right border from the cells in the last column:

```
table > tbody > tr > td:last-child { border-right: 0; }
```

Remove the bottom border from the cells in the last row:

```
table > tbody > tr:last-child > td { border-bottom: 0; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hzru0ytx/

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

HTML:

```
<table frame="void" rules="all">
```

CSS:

```
td, th {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```