# disabling table border in a column wise

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I want to disable border in a table by selecting a column, i dont want to see any border on the first row and first column of  my table.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="border-left:0; border-left-color:white; border-top: none;">
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
         Header text
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
        One
      </td>
      <td>
           One 1
      </td>
      <td>
           One 2
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
          Two
      </td>
      <td>
           Two 1
      </td>
      <td>
            Two 2
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

On the above table i use the inline css to do that but i get the border grayed out not blank, i dont want to see the gray border.

Any Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problems

table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid black;

}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

while googling out, i found some related staff in here

[CSS - Border only inside the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257430/css-border-only-inside-the-table)