# Setting Internal Borders within table using css

Tags: html, css

Having read [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1257430/3436942) - which (don't get me wrong) works. But I can't seem to find a way of editing it for my requirements.

Currently, the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/8M2wp/) gives:

```
 Heading | Heading
---------+---------
 Row     | Row
---------+---------
 Row     | Row
---------+---------
 Row     | Row
```

How can i edit this to being:

```
 Heading | Heading
---------+---------
 Row     | Row
 Row     | Row
 Row     | Row
```

Instead?

I've tried quite a few combinations, but can never seem to get it to work! :(

---

I've also noticed that the accepted answer is +5 years old. 
Would it still be the 'better'/'best' solution?

---

BTW i'm not great at css (actually, i'm beyond terrible), and so would appreciate your help (after all, I ended up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8M2wp/2059/) - ***completely*** wrong!).

Comment: I may be wrong, but you are after something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chriz123/8M2wp/2060/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `table tr:last-child td` group (since it'll be redundant) and add styles to remove any top or bottom border from your `<td>`s.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:first-child th {
    border-top: 0;
}

/* ---- This change --------- */
table tr td {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top:0;
}
/* ------------- */

table tr td:first-child,
table tr th:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
table tr td:last-child,
table tr th:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell (1,1)</td>
        <td>Cell (1,2)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell (2,1)</td>
        <td>Cell (2,2)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell (3,1)</td>
        <td>Cell (3,2)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: would there be a way of setting it to only this specific table (other tables might have different styling) i.e. making it have a unique class ?

Comment: Of course, if your table has a targetable attribute, for example an `id`: `#myTable tr td{ }`.

Comment: so that's remove the word **table** and replace it with **#myTablesID**?

Comment: Either that or `table#MyTable` but since `id`s need to be unique document-wide, there is no need.

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8M2wp/2062/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="inner">Cell (1,1)</td>
        <td class="inner">Cell (1,2)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="inner">Cell (2,1)</td>
        <td class="inner">Cell (2,2)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="inner">Cell (3,1)</td>
        <td class="inner">Cell (3,2)</td>
    </tr>
</table>

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:first-child th {
    border-top: 0;
}
table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
table tr td:first-child,
table tr th:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
table tr td:last-child,
table tr th:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}

.inner {
    border-bottom:1px white solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this in your css with your th, so it will add bottom border to your th.

```
table tr th{
    border:0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-color:black;
}
```