# Removing outer border in html table

Tags: html, css

I am developing a report in HTML. There I have a table. In each TD I have another table. I want to separate each table within td. So I have enabled the border of the main table. But few of the internal table need to display the cell borders. But I don't want the outer border of that particular internal table to display.

Ex.

```
<table ID="main" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table ID="INTER1">
                <tr>
                    <td>Table1 without internal border</td>
                <tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table ID="INTER2">
                <tr>
                    <td>Table with internal border</td>
                <tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

I want to do this using CSS class. I have googled for it but I found the solution which will apply for all the  tags, but that means it will remove outer border of all the tables.

Can I have have the solution for above problem?

Comment: Can you show your css and preferably create a code snippet on here or a fiddle?

Comment: "In each TD i have another table." — That is usually a sign that you shouldn't be using a table.

Comment: select it after id (if I understand correctly what you want)

Comment: can you draw? kinda confused tho

Comment: "I want to do this using CSS class. I have googled for it but i found the solution which will apply for all the tags." — That's odd. The **entire** point of using a class is so that you don't apply something to all elements (or even all elements of a particular type)

Comment: I think you need to add an image to visually describe the desired output

Comment: You can't disable the `#main` border?

Comment: am not sure what you want but try to use border-collapse: collapse;  in all tables

Comment: @Kash see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35573737/1966247 , I hope you want that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I apply a border only inside a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257430/how-can-i-apply-a-border-only-inside-a-table)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is how you can do it, you just need to add the `n-bordered` `class` to each table where you don't want the outer borders.

```css
.border-none {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
}

.border-none td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.border-none tr:first-child td {
  border-top: none;
}

.border-none tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.border-none tr td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.border-none tr td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="border-none">
   <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
      <td>Cell 5</td>
      <td>Cell 6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Cell 7</td>
      <td>Cell 8</td>
      <td>Cell 9</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Cell 10</td>
      <td>Cell 11</td>
      <td>Cell 12</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: impressive, and thanks. if doing for a page length limited assignment, overlooking style guides and putting semicolon etc in same line would save quite a lot of length. just for curiousity's sake, is there any other way to shorten the style a bit? or maybe some way to combine those?

Comment: also, it will also require adding th elements in selectors, so, any way to combine sibling elements while selections? i only know to specify them in full length, so:  `.border-none tr:first-child td, .border-none tr:first-child th` which's quite verbose and unpleasant to look at. some way to specify sibling would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you want, so review this and maybe we can progressively resolve this. According to Mr. Sweeney, you don't want the inner tables' borders but you still want the outer table's border. The dashed black line shows where the 2 inner table borders are. In the code are comments on how to remove them.

```css
table#main { border: 2px dashed blue; border-collapse: collapse; }
td { border: 1px solid red; height: 80px; }
td table { border: 1px dashed black; }

/* Replace the last line with this one */
/* td table { border: none; } */
```

```html
<table ID="main" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table ID="INTER1">
                <tr>
                    <td>Table1 without internal border</td>
                <tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table ID="INTER2">
                <tr>
                    <td>Table with internal border</td>
                <tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>
  <ul>
  <li>Blue Dashed = Outer Table</li>
  <li>Black Dashed = Inner Table</li>
  <li>Red Solid = Cell</li>
```

Comment: The op said: `So I have enabled the border of the main table.` yet you have set it to `none`?

Comment: Look at the title, are you 100% sure of what OP wants? If so, please enlighten me. :-)

Comment: I think the key word is `in` - removing the outer border of a table `within` a table - I agree though, it's open to misconception

Comment: Actually, the more I read this the more confused I get ha ha - time to move on - I've reversed the down vote

Comment: IKR? I put my money on what you said, it seems logical enough.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney zer00ne see answer I think he want something like that  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35573737/1966247

Comment: Oh, I see, so you're saying that he wants a way to use a class assignment in order to pick what borders he wants and what he doesn't want. Well you sir, are probably right. I think interpreting OP's question is a topic more popular than the actual issue at hand. Upvote from me.

Comment: the question is a bit hard to explain and thank for the upvote :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can just specify which tables you want to remove the border from. Like so:

```
td table, td table th, td table td {
   border: 0;
}
```

The above selects every `table`,`th` and `td` within another `td`. The highest-level table will be unaffected.

To style the each `td`s of a table differently, use their `id`s. Then do something like:

```
#INTER1 td {
  border: 0;
}

#INTER2 td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

If you have more `td` elements and you only want to style one of them, you can do the other approach as per above.

```
#INTER2 td:nth-of-type(2) {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```