# Setting a CSS border grid on a table: problem keeping line widths consistent

Tags: html, css, html-table

What's the best way to fill a table with a 1px grid (internal and external)? Or, possibly, do Chrome and Edge have a problem with borders in some cases?

This [Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/IwwdpSSJKF) does the obvious thing - it sets `border-right` and `border-bottom` on the `table`, and sets `border-top` and `border-left` on `td,th`. However, this doesn't work well. It looks good on Android and Firefox (HD/1080 on Windows, UHD/4K on Linux). It's flawed on Edge and Chrome (with Chrome on both Windows and Linux). It's mostly Ok, but some internal and external borders look like 2px.

Note that I'm not, I hope, just being dumb here. There are lots of similar questions on the web, but I can't get any consistency across browsers. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1257487/785194), for example, has a jsFiddle which displays differently on Firefox (108.0.2) and Chrome (108.0.5359.125). The Chrome version shows a double-width border for the top and bottom vertical lines, and a single-width one for the middle line. Firefox looks good.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a problem with your Chrome? I see the tables exactly the same in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @JoanLara - interesting. But my Chrome on this box is up-to-date, and Edge shows exactly the same problem, presumably sharing the same code base as Chrome? Besides, I've got a feeling that I've seen this on and off for years now, and ignored it.

Comment: This is how I see the table in both browsers: https://imgur.com/a/2nFcHtr

Comment: That's weird, thanks. I'm going to have a go at Windows display settings to see if it makes a difference. I also see the problem on Linux, but that's via a VNC connection with display on Windows, but I think VNC sends bit maps.

Comment: @JoanLara: so, Chrome and Edge show occasional incorrect widths when the display scaling is set to 150%, but look good on 100% and 200% (Win10).  *But* 100% and 200% are unusable on UHD, and 150% is recommended by MS. Firefox somehow gets around this. I'll need to check this on a 1080px laptop. Not sure how this fits in with my Linux result.

Answer (score 0):

**Chrome (and, by extension, Edge) are broken when scaling 1px borders.**

This doesn't apply to Firefox (I haven't noticed it, anyway). For Win10 and Win11, a 1px border sometimes displays at the minimum width when the display scaling is not 100%, and sometimes gets wider. If you have two lines next to each other one can appear to be "1 pixel" on a 125% display (most laptops), but the next one can appear to be "2 pixels". This means that you can't, for example, just set all borders to 1px when filling in the grid on a table.

There's an easy fix, though - just set the borders to 0.1px instead. [**This Codeply**](https://www.codeply.com/p/txnpO1pXl9) is the 0.1px version of the one in the question, and displays correctly on:

- Win 10, UHD/4K, display 150%, Firefox, Chrome, Edge
- Win 11, HD/1080, display 125%, Firefox, Chrome, Edge
- Android
- Ubuntu 22, Firefox and Chromium

Not sure how display scaling is handled in Ubuntu, and I'm also viewing the results on Win10 with VNC, which might complicate the issue.

Comment: This behavior might be changing in Chrome 109. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1201762, whose fix is included in 109.

Comment: @dgrogan: thanks, looks good. Impressed that you spotted this question.